# How do you make long list comprehensions in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example:

```
>>> [x for x in range(y) for y in range(z) for z in range(3)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

I would expect this to behave the same as:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> for z in range(3):
...   for y in range(z):
...     for x in range(3):
...       a.append(x)
... 
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: The [documentation for comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) explains this. Maybe it could be written more nicely, but "… considering each of the for or if clauses a block, nesting from left to right" seems to say pretty clearly that you will get the exact opposite nesting order from what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current comprehension will work if you reverse the order of the loops:

```
[x for z in range(3) for y in range(z) for x in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the loop in the same order in which you would in traditional for loop:

```
>>> [x for z in range(3) for y in range(z) for x in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can think of list comprehension this way:

```
[x for z in range(3)
       for y in range(z)
         for x in range(3) ]
```

Just remove the colons, wrap the for loops in brackets and have `x` at the front.